# Restfb lib on android with proguard

Tags: android, proguard, restfb

I'm using the [restfb](http://restfb.com/) library in my android project, everything works super fine. 
When I try to run proguard with it, it's completed successfully, but when running the app I get a

> com.restfb.exception.FacebookJsonMappingException: You must specify the Java type to map to.
>           at com.restfb.DefaultJsonMapper.toJavaList(Unknown Source)

my proguard-project.txt contains the lines

```
-keep class com.restfb.** { *; }
-keep interface com.restfb.** { *; }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON mapper probably uses introspection to find generic type information. ProGuard's obfuscation step removes it by default, because the virtual machine doesn't need it, but you can preserve it:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```